# Comparing json response from android to external json url in php server

Tags: php, android, json, mysqli

I would like to compare a barcode which entered by mobileuser from android app to the json url i received from merchant on the server side using php.

Assume this is my mobile user data(hardcoded):

```
$mobile_card="Card1";
$mobile_code="00004000";
```

This is the json url i received:

```
$merchant = file_get_contents('http://localhost/project1/index.php/memberaccount/sendjson');
$decode=json_decode($merchant, true);
```

There are two row of data in the json url:

```
 [{"merchant_code":"12300000","merchant_contact":"011000000"},        
{"merchant_code":"00004000","merchant_contact":"0123456789"}]
```

This is my code for comparing the $mobile_code to the $merchant_code:

```
foreach ($decode as $d)
                {
                    $merchantCode = $d['merchant_code']; 

                    if ($merchantCode == $mobile_code)
                    {
                       $response["success"] = 1;
                       $response["message"] = "code Exists.";
                       echo json_encode($response);


                    }  
                    else
                     {
                            $response["success"] = 0;
                            $response["message"] = "code NOT Exists";
                            echo json_encode($response);

                        }
                }
         }
```

This is output i get:

```
{"success":0,"message":"Code NOT exists"}

{"success":1,"message":"Code Exists."}
```

**However, I just want the output to be just one line, in this case, the code exists in second row, So I just want the result to show the success and existed result. (showing "Barcode existed" only)**

I do not want the unsuccessful result.
Anyone can help?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like that :

```
foreach ($decode as $d)
{
    $merchantCode = $d['merchant_code']; 
    if ($merchantCode == $mobile_code)
    {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "code Exists.";
        echo json_encode($response);
        die();
     }  
}

$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "code NOT Exists";
echo json_encode($response);
```

Or if you want to be a bit more elegant (using `die()` is not very nice), encapsulate the code inside a function :

```
function lookupMerchantCode($merchants, $code) 
{
   foreach ($merchants as $merchant)
    {
        $merchantCode = $merchant['merchant_code']; 
        if ($merchantCode == $code)
        {
            return true;
        }  
    }
    return false;
}

$result = lookupMerchantCode($decode, $mobile_code);

if ($result) 
{
     echo json_encode(array('success' => 1, 'message' => 'code Exists'));
}
else
{
     echo json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'message' => 'code NOT Exists'));
}
```

Comment: It works !!! Then if i gonna call another function in the if statement, Eg: $this -> actionValidatePhone();   I shud put before die(); right? or i should put after it?

Comment: Use the 2nd solution, it is better to encapsulate the logic inside a function.

Comment: Sorry, what that mean by:encapsulate the logic inside a function?

Comment: It is just a fancy word to say put the code that is supposed to check if the merchant code exists inside a function. Look at the 2nd part of my answer with that function : `function lookupMerchantCode($merchants, $code)`